# Crystal Reports - Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de visualizar un reporte generado con crystal reports, montado desde un servidor local de windows y utilizando asp.net.

El mismo se visualiza de manera correcta con el navegador:
Chrome[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuestión, es que cuando el mismo reporte lo intento visualizar desde Firefox, se presenta de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un principio no funcionaba en ninguno, modificando un poco las opciones del Administrador IIS, habilite la opción que permite aplicaciones de 32 bits, y ahi fue cuando llegue a este punto.

¿Alguien ha tenido un inconveniente similar?

Saludos,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, bastaba con añadir lo siguiente ClientTarget="uplevel", en las directivas del archivo aspx que funciona de visualizador.

```
<%@ Page ClientTarget="uplevel" ... %>
```